# Attempted import error : 'unstable_composeClasses' is not exported from '@mui/utils' (imported as 'composeClasses'

Tags: npm, stacked-bar-chart, mui-x-charts

I am creating a Stacked Bar for an application. I have imported the x-charts in package.json file.
We are using npm and While running the code, it is showing me following error repetitively.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUHj7.png)

My package.json file looks like this,

```
{
  "name": "ipm_ui",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-io/moment": "^2.11.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.4.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^5.0.0-beta.5",
    "@mui/base": "^5.0.0-alpha.97",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.0.1",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.49",
    "@mui/material": "^5.0.2",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.0.1",
    "@mui/x-charts": "^6.19.5",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.0.0-beta.7",
    "@mui/x-data-grid-pro": "^5.0.0-beta.7",
    "@react-pdf/renderer": "^2.1.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "aws-amplify": "^3.3.26",
    "aws-amplify-react": "^4.2.30",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.0.0-beta.5",
    "jsbarcode": "^3.11.5",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.37",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-barcode": "^1.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.21.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^4.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-select": "^5.2.1",
    "react-switch": "^6.0.0",
    "react-to-pdf": "0.0.14",
    "socks-proxy-agent": "^7.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.17.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build && CI=false && npm run post-build",
    "post-build": "node ./lib/post-build.js",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Why this could be occuring and How to solve it.

I went to node_modules and checked this, those files seems normal